# E: Unable to locate package python-gudev

Tags: python

This simple command:

`sudo apt-get install -y python-gudev`

is giving this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-gudev
```

This is on ubuntu 20.04 Server. I've looked and looked and can't find the solution.

Comment: Do you mean this <https://github.com/nzjrs/python-gudev>? It looks like the project is dead, it hasn't been updated in years, all commits are from 2010, except one pull request from 2014. The most recent `python-gudev` Debian package I could find (for Debian Stretch) depends on Python 2.7, which reached end-of-life on 1/1/2020, and it doesn't seem like there's a Python 3 version available.

Comment: Yeah... It's used by linorobot which was based on 2.7 but that we are trying to run with 3.7. I did find this: - Sudo apt-get install -y gir1.2-gudev-1.0... Does that make sense to you?